# Shrink Disk and NTFS MetaFile Defragmentation ($BITMAP)

Tags: bitmap, ntfs, sysinternals, defragmentation

Shrink Disk and Defragmentation

I'm trying to shrink a disk. The volume is about 1 To large, and only 200 Go are curretly used.
It is a virtual disk.

When i ask to the disk management tool to shrink my disk, it lets me shrink only 73 Go and says that the $Bitmap::DATA file prevents to shrink more.

I tried to use several tools to defragment this file, no success..
I used OSForensics tool, i saw that this file ($Bitmap) has 35 fragments (and the Last used cluster corresponds to 1 To - 73 Go)

My goal is to script every operation to shrink a disk. (because i need to do it on multiple server)
I used contig tool (from sysinternals) to defragment this file,
but i get an "Access denied" Error.

Tried to use contig, from a live CD (malakal), same result..

Does anybody knows a way to defragment this file ?

Thanks for your answers...

Marc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.